# (AHK) How to Click X times, wait, then repeat

Tags: loops, automation, macros, click, autohotkey

Trying to code an auto clicker that clicks x times, waits, then repeats using AutoHotkey. Currently, this is the code I have down:

```
SetMouseDelay, 500
F3::
stop := 0
Loop
{
    Loop, 5
    {
       Click ;
       break ;
    }
    Sleep, 5000
}until Stop
return

F4::Stop := 1
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here but it will only click once then wait 5 seconds then click once again whereas the code is meant to get it to click 5 times then sleep for 5 seconds. Any help fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove [`Break`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Break.htm), not sure why you had it in there anyway.